# How to include angular-bootstrap in existing angularjs application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

Assuming one has already built a simple front end in angularjs, what are the steps needed to follow in order to include angularjs-bootstrap in front end and use the corresponding directives and css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `'ui.bootstrap'` to `angular.module`:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

and sure import bootstrap javascript + css to your header

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is one of the best part of AngularJs MV * framework. You can inject it in the cntroller